How to get whatever type belongs to a key in an interface by the name of the key?
I need a function that returns the type of a key in an given interface T:
function getTypeOfKey<T>(key: keyof T) {
  // how to return the type that belongs to the key?
}

interface Person {
  email: string;
  age: number;
}

console.log(getTypeOfKey<Person>("email")); 

I know it works when you supply an object:
const person: Person = {
  email: "someemail@email.com",
  age: 81,
};

function getTypeOfKeyWithObj<T>(obj: T, key: keyof T) {
  return typeof obj[key];
}

console.log(getTypeOfKeyWithObj<Person>(person, "email")); // string
console.log(getTypeOfKeyWithObj<Person>(person, "age")); // number

But can I make it work without having to send the entire object into the function?
I tried this but it's not valid:
function getTypeTest<T>(key: keyof T) {
  type keyType = T[key];
  return keyType;
}


That information doesn't exist at runtime, TypeScript's type metadata is erased in transpilation to JavaScript.

To elaborate: the TypeScript code getTypeOfKey<Person>("email") will be emitted as the JavaScript getTypeOfKey("email"). No trace of Person exists there. If you want to pass in an actual object of type Person, or build some kind of type schema system where Person is a constructor or other runtime representation of the type, maybe you can get behavior like this, but as asked the answer to the question is a curt "this is impossible". If you want alternative suggestions, please [edit] the question to clarify the use case more. Otherwise this will probably be closed as a duplicate.

Ok thanks. When is see the transpiled JS code I see what you mean. And if I go the route of using the object I still run into the problem of when the object field is undefined or null. I will just go another route then, and not use this.
